# Sort and remove duplicate photos

Tags: hard-drive, photos.app, photos

I have been trying to collate all my photos & remove the duplicated ones. I have purchased a few apps but none do the job properly, they are still there the next day, I have 3 hard drives so plenty of space. The pictures seem to get duplicated every time I try something. I have tried iPhoto but still get the same problem.

Comment: If the pictures seem to re-duplicate after you have deleted them, it might be better to turn off whatever is causing the duplication first. Please ask a new question if you need assistance in doing so.

Comment: Regarding the removing of duplicates: how are your photos organized? Are you using some kind of folder structure, or iPhoto/other application? Do you take pictures with an iPhone and use iCloud syncing to get the onto your computer?

Answer (score 1):

There are many options – and at least three different approaches to this:

- Use a third party application to find (and remove) duplicate files. Probably the most convenient option – there is a variety of different apps like [Duplicate Detective](https://fiplab.com/apps/duplicate-detective-for-mac) available – but you'll have to buy a license. There used to be a free demo version of [Gemini](http://macpaw.7eer.net/c/17038/63813/1733), if you just want to find duplicates and delete them yourself. Haven't tried it for years though.
- Use the search function of your finder. This is a bit clumsy, but good method to find duplicates occasionally. You can search for "*" (asterix/wildcard) and then narrow your results down by using the filters and the sort options – e.g. "only images, modified after 1st of January 2014" or the like.
- Use Terminal Commands or Apple Script. You should probably only go this direction if you know what you're doing.

There is a blog post "[How to Find and Delete Duplicate Files in Mac OS X](http://www.chriswrites.com/how-to-find-and-delete-duplicate-files-in-mac-os-x/)" that goes deeper into these three approaches.

Comment: Does Gemini work on Photos libraries as well as iPhoto libraries?